# PrimeFaces Lazydatamodel showing no records

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

This was about PrimeFaces lazy loading

```
<h:head>
    <title>data table with pagination</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3>datatable with pagination</h3>
    <p:dataTable var="lazemp" value="#{lazy.lazy1}" paginator="true" rows="8"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,8,11" lazy="true">
        <p:column headerText="ID">
            <h:outputText value="#{lazemp.id}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="NAME">
            <h:outputText value="#{lazemp.name}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="SPECIFICATION">
            <h:outputText value="#{lazemp.specification}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Here it has to fetch the data from this java file.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "lazy")
@RequestScoped
public class Lazyload {

    private LazyDataModel<Employee> lazy1;

    public LazyDataModel<Employee> getLazy1() {
        return lazy1;
    }

    public void setLazy(LazyDataModel<Employee> lazy1) {
        this.lazy1 = lazy1;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        lazy1 = new LazyDataModel<Employee>() {

            public ArrayList<Employee> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, boolean sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
                Employee e1 = new Employee();
                e1.setId(1);
                e1.setName("solo");
                e1.setSpecification("java");
                Employee e2 = new Employee();
                e2.setId(2);
                e2.setName("shamin");
                e2.setSpecification("spring");
                Employee e3 = new Employee();
                e3.setId(3);
                e3.setName("pranesh");
                e3.setSpecification("php");
                Employee e4 = new Employee();
                e4.setId(4);
                e4.setName("ravi");
                e4.setSpecification("pearl");

                Employee e5 = new Employee();
                e5.setId(5);
                e5.setName("bopara");
                e5.setSpecification("onrails");
                Employee e6 = new Employee();
                e6.setId(6);
                e6.setName("anish");
                e6.setSpecification("unix");

                Employee e7 = new Employee();
                e7.setId(7);
                e7.setName("darwin");
                e7.setSpecification("c");
                Employee e8 = new Employee();
                e8.setId(8);
                e8.setName("gangadaran");
                e8.setSpecification("hibenate");
                Employee e9 = new Employee();
                e9.setId(9);
                e9.setName("cyrus");
                e9.setSpecification("python");
                Employee e10 = new Employee();
                e10.setId(10);
                e10.setName("senthil");
                e10.setSpecification("testing");
                Employee e11 = new Employee();
                e11.setId(11);
                e11.setName("balaji");
                e11.setSpecification("dijango");
                Employee e12 = new Employee();
                e12.setId(12);
                e12.setName("kannan");
                e12.setSpecification("visualc");
                Employee e13 = new Employee();
                e13.setId(13);
                e13.setName("beljo");
                e13.setSpecification("angular js");
                Employee e14 = new Employee();
                e14.setId(14);
                e14.setName("ananthu");
                e14.setSpecification("css");
                Employee e15 = new Employee();
                e15.setId(15);
                e15.setName("kuttan");
                e15.setSpecification("c++");
                Employee e16 = new Employee();
                e16.setId(16);
                e16.setName("mani");
                e16.setSpecification("cobol");
                Employee e17 = new Employee();
                e17.setId(17);
                e17.setName("sangakara");
                e17.setSpecification("ceylon");
                Employee e18 = new Employee();
                e18.setId(3);
                e18.setName("solop");
                e18.setSpecification("scala");
                Employee e19 = new Employee();
                e19.setId(19);
                e19.setName("bryant");
                e19.setSpecification("java");
                Employee e20 = new Employee();
                e20.setId(20);
                e20.setName("lynn");
                e20.setSpecification(".net");
                Employee e21 = new Employee();
                e21.setId(21);
                e21.setName("shen");
                e21.setSpecification("angularjs");
                Employee e22 = new Employee();
                e22.setId(22);
                e22.setName("jacob");
                e22.setSpecification("ajax");
                Employee e23 = new Employee();
                e23.setId(3);
                e23.setName("paul");
                e23.setSpecification("gwt");
                ArrayList<Employee> lazyemp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                lazyemp.add(e1);
                lazyemp.add(e2);
                lazyemp.add(e3);
                lazyemp.add(e4);
                lazyemp.add(e5);
                lazyemp.add(e6);
                lazyemp.add(e7);
                lazyemp.add(e8);
                lazyemp.add(e9);
                lazyemp.add(e10);
                lazyemp.add(e11);
                lazyemp.add(e12);
                lazyemp.add(e13);
                lazyemp.add(e14);
                lazyemp.add(e15);
                lazyemp.add(e16);
                lazyemp.add(e17);
                lazyemp.add(e18);
                lazyemp.add(e19);
                lazyemp.add(e20);
                lazyemp.add(e21);
                lazyemp.add(e22);
                lazyemp.add(e23);

                return lazyemp;
            }
        };
        lazy1.setRowCount(15);
    }
}
```

On running getting only the column text with no data ,showing no records present I'm stuck any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please also refer to the PrimeFaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml). It is not for decoration only :) Avoid that anonymous class and extends your bean using [`LazyDataModel<T>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.1/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html) and override precisely one of those overloaded methods `load()` based on the sorting strategy single or multiple in your application.

Comment: still showing no records found

Comment: Please consider editing the existing post or start a brand new thread with the new changes you made in your code but please do not forget to consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).